# Can I open a Help To Buy ISA if I've already opened a cash ISA this year? Are all HTB ISAs Cash ISAs?

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

Suppose I've opened a cash ISA this tax year, and I top it up every month. It's not yet reached the yearly maximum of £15,240.

As I understand it, [I can't open a second cash ISA this tax year](http://www.moneywise.co.uk/banking-saving/savings-accounts-isas/can-i-pay-two-isas-one-tax-year), but I can open a stocks and shares ISA, so long as I don't invest more than £15,240 between the two.

Can I open a Help To Buy aka First Time Buyer's ISA? (obviously assuming I meet the first time buyer's criteria) I'm not sure if they count as Cash, or a third type, or if some are Cash and some are Stocks & Shares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [user568458's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/57590/36242) the Help To Buy ISA does count as a cash ISA.

However, it's worth noting that some providers count all of your "cash ISAs" with them as one ISA for the purposes of the one-per-year limit. This means you may be able to pay into both a Help To Buy ISA and a standard cash ISA in the same year **with the same provider**, depending of course on your provider.

---

For example, the [Nationwide Building Society's Help To Buy ISA information](http://www.nationwide.co.uk/products/savings/help-to-buy-isa/features-and-benefits) includes this text:

> (You can contribute to another Nationwide cash ISA product at the same time, as long as you don't exceed your total ISA tax-free savings allowance each year.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in [an official government document, titled Help to Buy: ISA scheme outline](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/413899/Help_to_Buy_ISA_Guidance.pdf)

> 3.9 As is currently the case, it will only be possible for a saver to subscribe to one cash ISA per year. It will therefore not be possible for an account holder to subscribe to a Help to Buy: ISA with one provider, and another cash ISA with a different provider.

It doesn't explicitly say that all HTB ISAs are a sub type of cash ISA in so many words, but this isn't the only section to very strongly imply it:

> 3.7 Saving into a Help to Buy: ISA will also be very similar to saving into any other cash ISA account...

It's consistently talked about as if it's a sub-type of cash ISA.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a HTB ISA and Cash ISA with certain providers - restrictions are that HTB and Cash ISA must be with the same provider.

Other UK portfolio providers are:

- Nationwide
- Aldermore
- NatWest
- Ulster Bank
- Newcastle Building Society

Source: http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/help-to-buy-ISA#aldermore