# Help in understanding the limitations of new ISA opening/transfers

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

Apologies for a non-specific question - I found it impossible to express it within the 150 character limit.

I have paid some money to my old Cash ISA this year already. I want to open a new one and I know I can do it as long as I transfer the balance. Does that refer to the entire balance of my existing ISA or only on the amount paid in this year?

This follows up my [previous question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/98361/can-i-open-a-help-to-buy-isa-transferring-a-part-of-my-existing-cash-isa-if-i) relating to HTB ISAs.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean tax year here, rather than calendar year.

You can only pay **new** money into one cash ISA in any given tax year.  Whether that's a newly opened ISA or one you opened previously makes no difference.

But you can transfer money from one ISA to another as much as you like.  Just make sure you transfer the money.  Don't withdraw it, and then attempt to pay it into the other ISA, because then it loses it's special ISA status.